# nginx + php with drupal + codeigniter in separate folders

Tags: php, drupal, codeigniter, nginx, url-rewriting

I have a Slicehost slice for a dev server, with nginx and PHP.

I'm trying to get drupal running on localhost/drupal and a codeigniter app running on localhost/codeigniter.

I can get one or the other to work, but not both -- the rewrite and fastcgi seem to be interfering with one another.

Does anyone know how to have /drupal and /codeigniter both working, with rewrite rules (for SEF URLs), in separate folders in my /var/www?

Cheers.

Comment: Can't you set them as [VirtualHost](http://wiki.nginx.org/VirtualHostExample)s ?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have to create a file (no extension needed) in /etc/nginx/sites-available that represents the name of your folder/domain (ex: drupal, yoursite.com).

**Here's a sample file:**

```
server {
 server_name yourdomain.com;
 root /var/www/yourdomain;

 index index.php;

   location / {
     autoindex on;
     try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
   }
   location ~ \.php$ {
     fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
     fastcgi_index index.php;
     include fastcgi_params;
   }
}
```

In the sample above it will actually send url rewrites to **$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']**. For more nginx rewrites, you can take a look at http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule for more reference.

Then you want to enable it by creating a symlink of this file in your /etc/nginx/sites-enabled folder

```
Example: # ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yoursite /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/yoursite
```

Then restart/reload nginx

```
 # services nginx reload
```